# Ionic 4: ionic serve reloads app on every page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm new to Ionic 4 and I'm trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong, or if Ionic 4 just acts differently in this area.  I have a very simple app that just  has a few Ionic pages, and in the `app.component.ts` file I trigger some init logic in the `platform.ready()` call.  I noticed this init code was fired on every page load when testing via `ionic serve`.  Some code is below.  I assume `ionic serve` is supposed to only reload the app when the code changes (and not on every navigation to a new page)?  Maybe my navigation approach is causing the app to reload?

**app.component.ts**

```
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      let time = new Date().toLocaleString();
      console.log(`${time}: Platform is ready...dude`);
    });
  }
```

Simple navigation that loads various empty pages (and seems to trigger an app reload on every nav).

**Home.page.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<h1>Home Page</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/home" routerDirection="root">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="/login" routerDirection="root">login</a></li>
    <li><a href="/profile" routerDirection="root">profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/signup" routerDirection="root">signup</a></li>
    <li><a href="/account" routerDirection="forward">accounts</a></li>    
    <li><a href="/admin" routerDirection="forward">admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'profile', loadChildren: './pages/profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule' },
  { path: 'account-detail/:id', loadChildren: './pages/account-detail/account-detail.module#AccountDetailPageModule' },
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: './pages/account/account.module#AccountPageModule' },
  { path: 'settlement', loadChildren: './pages/settlement/settlement.module#SettlementPageModule' },
  { path: 'signup', loadChildren: './pages/signup/signup.module#SignupPageModule' },
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: './pages/admin/admin.module#AdminPageModule' },
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rookie mistake.  I'm posting an answer in case anyone else stumbles into this.

My issue was the anchor tags.  Obviously I'm unfamiliar with the angular router.  Looks like if you provide a `routerLink` it will do what we'd expect from a "normal" SPA link (as opposed to reloading the app).

**Updated Home Page**

```
<ion-content padding>
<h1>Home Page</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/home']" routerDirection="root">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/login']" routerDirection="root">login</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/profile']" routerDirection="root">profile</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/signup']" routerDirection="root">signup</a></li>
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/account']" routerDirection="forward">accounts</a></li>    
    <li><a [routerLink]="['/admin']" routerDirection="forward">admin</a></li>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```